# How to check if an element has CSS and If so Update its parent with those?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to check whether `<img>` has defined inline `css` property, and if so It need to update its parent with those `css` and need to remove orginal css declaration.

This is how I tried it:

```
var $el = $('.article > img');
$el.each(function () {
  if ($(this).css("float") == "left") { $(this).parent().css("float","left"); }
  if ($(this).css("float") == "right") { $(this).parent().css("float","right"); }
})
```

My img tag would have css for `float` or `margin` and somethime both or none of them. My above code is working for only for one rule.

Can anybody tell me how do it for both `CSS` rules?

Comment: `working for only for one rule` is something like `$(this).css("float") == "left || $(this).css('margin') === 'something'` can help?

Comment: I tried it something like @MoshFeu has mentioned. but margin would have different values. ex: `margin: 0 10px 0, margin: 10px, margin: 5px 20px` ect.. not like `float`

Comment: So you just want to find out if it has `margin` at all? `$(this).css("float") == "left || $(this).css('margin')` (`$(this).css('margin')` means - has `margin`)

Comment: @MoshFeu `var margin = $(this).css('margin'); alert(margin);` gives blank in firefox. But margin is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if the images have any `float` or `margin` properties and then set the parent with those values like:

```js
var $el = $('.article > img');
$el.each(function() {
  const float = $(this).css('float')
  const marginT = $(this).css('margin-top')
  const marginL = $(this).css('margin-left')
  const marginR = $(this).css('margin-right')
  const marginB = $(this).css('margin-bottom')

  // Set the css to the parent based on child img
  if (float !== 'none') $(this).parent().css("float", float);
  if (marginT !== '0px' && marginT !== '')
    $(this).parent().css("margin-top", marginT);
  if (marginL !== '0px' && marginT !== '')
    $(this).parent().css("margin-left", marginL);
  if (marginR !== '0px' && marginT !== '')
    $(this).parent().css("margin-right", marginR);
  if (marginB !== '0px' && marginT !== '')
    $(this).parent().css("margin-bottom", marginB);

  // Remove the original image css
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
})
```

```css
.article { border: 1px solid red}
img {width: 50px;height: 50px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">
  <img alt="Image 1" style="float:left" />
</div>
<div class="article">
  <img alt="Image 2" style="margin: 5px 70px" />
</div>
<div class="article">
  <img alt="Image 3" style="float:right;margin: 10px" />
</div>
```

Please note:

- If there is no `float` applied on the element, then `$(this).css('float')` return `none`.
- If there is no `margin-top` applied on the element, then `$(this).css('margin-top')` return `0px` and so on..

So, we are simply using this logic to update the parent css.

Comment: You mean in this demo? I have tested this and this seems to work fine in this demo. I have also verified it in the chrome element console.Both float and margin are applied.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Its working on chrome but not in firefox

Comment: `alert(margin)` is blank in firefox

Comment: Great...Now its working nicely. Thank you very much

Comment: Notice that `marginT == ''` in FF (see OP [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575652/how-to-check-if-an-element-has-css-and-if-so-update-its-parent-with-those?noredirect=1#comment110663137_62575652)). So this check is basically does nothing in FF. Good answer though..

Comment: Yes, we can simply add `if(marginT !== '0px' || marginT !== '')` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [jquery.copycss.js](https://github.com/moagrius/copycss) plugin.

```
$('#some-element').copyCSS('#another-element');  // copy all styles
$('#some-element').copyCSS('#another-element', ['top', 'left']);  // copy just top and left
$('#some-element').copyCSS('#another-element', null, ['top', 'left']);  // copy everything except top and left
```